# NSTableView init width issue

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview

I have a `NSTableView` whose columns resize when the user reduce the width of the window.

But at init, the horizontal scrollview kicks in and the user does not see all columns by default. He has to scroll to see them. If the user increases the window's width, then reduce it, the scroll is gone and the columns widths are reduced to fit the width. Which is what I want.

How can I get rid of this initial behavior, i.e. prevent horizontal scroll at init.

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that
`tableView.sizeToFit()` does the job.